# animate scrollTop not working on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button with an href attribute and when i click on it, it will scroll to the div with id="buttonhref_value" ...I need some extra space before the div so that people can view my fixed menu bar on top..so its top - 60...it works fine in chrome, and safari..in IE no matter how much extra space i give ,it always scroll to the top of the div..i mean the  div is now below the menu bar..can anyone help ?

```
  $.fn.smoothScrollOnClick = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).on('click', function (event) {

        if (this.hash !== '') {
        var hash = this.hash;
        if ($('' + hash + '').length > 0) {
          var stop = ($('' + hash + '').offset().top - 60 );
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: stop
            }, 200, function () {
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        }
       }
     });
   });
  };
```

Comment: IE version ? :)

Comment: have you tried with console.log to get the value of `stop` ? and check it in IE console ? or to alert it or to write it on page. just to check if it is calculated

Comment: yes its been calculated..i can see the value

Comment: IE version is IE 11 and Firefox the latest version

Comment: Could that be because you're updating the hash after animating it to the right place?
Try to execute things in this order and see what happens:
1. prevent default
2. update hash
3. animate to correct place

Comment: Also, you can simply use `$(hash)` instead of `$('' + hash + '')`

Comment: hmm..let me try that way

Comment: Hey it worked..Thanks :)